# three.jsのwebXRにおいてコントローラーのパッド情報を受け取る方法

Tags: webapi, three.js

https://teratail.com/questions/rr9ib865n9y59q
こちらで同じ質問をしています。
three.jsのwebXRによってコントローラーのパッド情報に伴うイベントを追加したいです
コントローラーのパッド部分を動かすと表示しているオブジェクトも動かすようなイベントを追加したいです。
HTCVIVEを利用しています。
トリガーボタンの操作に関するイベントは公式のexampleにあるのですが、その他のボタンに関する操作はexampleで見つからないです
少し調べてみると2020年の６月段階ではwebXRではパッドの情報を取得できない?みたいなのですがその状況は現在も改善されてないのでしょうか?
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/listening-to-xr-touchpad-or-thumbstick-motion-controller-events/1754
今はもう廃止されているWebVRで動作するコードがあるのですが
このように書かれてるみたいです。

```
controller1.addEventListener('axischanged', move);でmoveイベント追加
〜〜〜〜
function move(event){
    if(this.getButtonState('thumbpad') && this.getButtonState('trigger') === false){
      var z = event.axes[0];
      var x = event.axes[1];
      group.position.x = group.position.x + 100 * x;
      group.position.z = group.position.z + 100* z;
    }
    if(this.getButtonState('thumbpad') && this.getButtonState('trigger')){
      var y = -event.axes[1];
      group.position.y = group.position.y + 100* y;
    }
  }
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/rr9ib865n9y59q) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: ただいま確認しました　了解です。